# Tate-Farrell cohomology of a circle

Tags: soft-question, reference-request, group-cohomology

I know my question is very imprecise. I am trying to understand Tate-Farrell cohomology of the infinite Lie group $S^1$ (say, with coefficients in $\mathbb C$). I would expect that the answer is something like the space of Laurent polynomials $\mathbb C[t^{-1},t]$. Is there any geometric intuition for this? What would be the meaning of multiplication by $t$? What is the meaning of the completion $\mathbb C((t))$?

Comment: Loran should probably be Laurent :)

Comment: Are you talking about S^1 as a discrete group, a topological group or a Lie group? Rather, what are you more interested in: S^1 or Tate-Farrell cohomology?

Comment: Lie group. More interested in S^1 :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Comment:** Farrell-Tate cohomology as defined in Brown's book "Cohomology of Groups" 
requires the group to be of finite virtual cohomological dimension (i.e. the group has a finite index subgroup which has a finite projective resolution). But $S^1$ doesn't have finite virtual cohomological dimension because it has finite subgroups of arbitrary order.

There is a generalization of Farrell-Tate cohomology for arbitrary groups due to Benson-Carlson/Mislin, that is usually called "complete cohomoloy" or "complete Tate cohomology". I don't know if that cohomology has been computed for $S^1$ (most computations are done for discrete groups).